# Get value of symbol defined inside object literal and iterate over its values

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an object literal like below.

```
{
  is_active: true,
  start_date: { [Symbol(lt)]: 2020-02-24T12:56:36.780Z },
  expiry_date: { [Symbol(gt)]: 2020-02-24T12:56:36.780Z },
  [Symbol(or)]: [ { user_id: 'M' }, { user_id: null } ]
}
```

*These objects are automatically generated by sequelize before querying to database*
I need to iterate through all object keys and change the value of that key which is `id` or ends with `_id`.
This is my first time with Symbol datatype. I read a article [here](https://javascript.info/symbol), It says they can't be iterate using `for...in` or `object...keys`
I also read an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734124/access-the-value-of-symbolid-property-on-an-object), but It only said how to access it.
Below is my function that iterate recursively though the object and decrypts `id` and value of keys ending with `_id`

```
   function decryptIds(obj) {
          if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
            for (let key in obj) {
              if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                for(let i = 0; i< obj[key].length; i++) {
                  if(typeof obj[key][i] === 'object' && obj[key][i] !==null)
                    decryptIds(obj[key][i].where)
                  else 
                    obj[key][i] = decrypt(obj[key][i])
                }
              } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj !== null) {
                decryptIds(obj[key].where)
              }
              else if (key === 'id' || key.endsWith('_id')) {
                obj[key] = decrypt(obj[key])
              }
            }
          }
          return
        }
        decryptIds(model.where)
```

Comment: why not use s/t iterable like `AND`, `OR`, etc as key?

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, I didn't put much information, I will update though. Those objects are auto generated by sequelize itself before querying to db. So I can't change them.

Comment: One of the purposes of symbols is to explicitly disallow this usecase--if you're constructing the query do the modification before you get the symbolized result.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I managed to do it. I know it's not the solution, it's easily feasible. I will keep try until I get any better approach. For now it is okay.

```
      beforeFind: (model, options) => {
        function decryptIds(obj) {
          if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj!==snull &&Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)) {
            const objectSymbols = obj[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)[0]]
            if(objectSymbols) {
              objectSymbols.forEach(el => {
                decryptIds(el)
              })
            }
          }
          if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
            for (let key in obj) {
              if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                for(let i = 0; i< obj[key].length; i++) {
                  if(typeof obj[key][i] === 'object' && obj[key][i] !==null)
                    decryptIds(obj[key][i].where)
                  else 
                    obj[key][i] = decrypt(obj[key][i])
                }
              }
              else if (key === 'id' || key.endsWith('_id')) {
                if(obj[key]) {
                  obj[key] = decrypt(obj[key])
                }
              } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj !== null) {
              decryptIds(obj[key].where)
            }
            }
          }
          return
        }
        console.log(model.where)
        decryptIds(model.where)
        console.log(model.where)
      },
```