# How to get the FULL url from the API route in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am wondering if there's a way for me to get the full URL of the current request inside the API route (pages/api/myapi), the only returned response I see that's close to what I need is the `req.headers.referer`, but I am not sure if this value will always be in the headers. The type for that is `string | undefined`.

There's also the `req.headers.host` and `req.headers.origin` but it's missing the protocol.

The end goal is to get the full URL inside my API handler function.i.e. "https://example.org/api/test"

Answer (score 5):

I see two options here.

#### Option 1

If the protocol is known (e.g. `http` or `https`), then combine

- `req.headers.host` - returns the *hostname* with the *portnumber*, e.g. `localhost:3000`
- `req.url` - returns the requested path, e.g. `/api/test`

#### Option 2

If the protocol is unknown, then we have to dig deeper to get the full URL.
The `req` object exposes in the `Symbol(NextRequestMeta)` key the following values

```js
{
  ...
  [Symbol(NextRequestMeta)]: {
    __NEXT_INIT_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/test',
    _protocol: 'http',

  }
}
```

There are [several approaches for accessing Symbol's properties in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734124/access-the-value-of-symbolid-property-on-an-object). One example to access `__NEXT_INIT_URL` would be:

```js
const nextRequestMeta = req[Reflect.ownKeys(req).find(
    (s) => String(s) === "Symbol(NextRequestMeta)"
)];
console.log(nextRequestMeta.__NEXT_INIT_URL); // -> http://localhost:3000/api/test
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to get the host from headers `Property 'host' does not exist on type 'Headers'`.